# pip build . similar to python setup.py build

Tags: python, pip

Instead of doing

```
python setup.py install
```

we can do

```
pip install .
```

But, it does not build the library rather installs the egg without building.

Is there any command to build from pip which works similar to

```
python setup.py build
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip install -e .
```

It builds and then installs.